# Compare Two strings and get the another Value

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here i'm facing some issue ,i get the Two arrays from server ,first array like this

```
[
    "AI",
    "AI",
    "9W",
    "9W",
    "AI",
    "AI",
    "9W"
]
```

and second Array like this,

```
                  [
                     {
                     "Name": "iMac",
                     "Image": null,
                     "Code": "9W"
                     },
                     {
                     "Name": "iPhone",
                     "Image": null,
                     "Code": "AI"
                     },
                   ]
```

but i need to based on first array code values compare to the second array `code` values then i need to get the respective `name`     ,i tried to sorting and fast enumeration but i can't get,can you please help how can i get ,thank you

Comment: Please show your `JSON` parsing code and any comparison code you've tried.

Comment: Use predicates...its will be enough

Comment: can you show complete json output please? instead split arrays @G.P.Reddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a predicate, looking for entries whose `Code` matches the value you're looking for:

```
NSArray *objects = @[@{@"Name": @"iMac", @"Image": [NSNull null], @"Code": @"9W"},
                     @{@"Name": @"iPhone", @"Image": [NSNull null], @"Code": @"AI"}];

NSString *code = @"AI";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Code=%@", code];
NSArray *matchingObjects = [objects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

And if you want the first matching item's name:

```
NSString *name = matchingObjects[0][@"Name"];
```

Comment: Thank you Working fine @Rob

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Swift example:

```
   let arrayOne = [
        "AI",
        "AI",
        "9W",
        "9W",
        "AI",
        "AI",
        "9W"
    ]

    let arrayTwo = [
        [
            "Name":"iMac",
            "Image":"null",
            "Code": "9W"
        ],
        [
            "Name": "iPhone",
            "Image": "null",
            "Code": "AI"
        ],
    ]

    for i in arrayTwo
    {
        if arrayOne .contains(i["Code"]!)
        {
            print(i["Name"]!)
        }
    }
```

Please try this code. Here you will get the Name which matches the first array